How to enclose this carport on uneven asphalt? wood frame between pillars or lay concrete slab first?
I'm trying to figure out the best way to enclose this carport pictured below. purpose is to have a jam space for me and my drummer, but also, sometimes do some woodworking in there away from the rain. thus, need to keep it dry.
The deck above it (the roof of the carport) was redone about 10 years, and is very solid. the pillars go very deep in the ground and are also solid. they are wood pillars on top of a concrete block/slab of some sort. around 7 years ago, asphalt was laid on top of uneven concrete under the carport.
i've got 3 options i thought of:

most expensive, rip/cut (via concrete saw) all the asphalt+concrete under the concrete (11 x 22 feet). level it, and pour new concrete on top. it would cover the space between the pillars, and thus, give a level ground for laying a 2x4 frame between the pillars, plus would give a nice 'garage' look.

leave the asphalt under the carport as-is - but - lay a narrow concrete slab between the pillars. either rip the asphalt out just between the pillars, or lay on top somehow of the asphalt and level it? either way, just provide a level base for laying a level wood frame between the pillars. this would be cheaper than #1.

just lay a 2x4 wood frame between the carport pillars. but, I'm not sure how to do this as it would be unlevel. is it possible to make that level somehow? then, what about water?


any advice? here is a picture of the said carport. located in Vancouver, Canada.



Wood is easy to cut/shape, so being uneven is not that much  of a problem.  Can also use a level line and build up, and fill in the bottom with small sections.

@crip659 i was more concerned about there being a gap between the bottom plate 2x4 and the asphalt, since it's not level between pillars. could i just simply use some sort of foam caulking to seal this?

Are you planning to HVAC the enclosed space?

@Huesmann no, no HVAC or electric. just enclosed.

@SolarMike to answer your question on logic, it was not logic that kept them there in the first place when the deck was rebuilt, but a matter of structure. the company that was hired out to do the asphalt, was unable to remove the concrete section of the pillars, they were dug extremely deep into the ground (in fact even with a huge tow truck and winches, they were unable to pull them out). a 4 man experienced crew was unable to pull them, so we left them.
